# Can SELECT but can't DELETE

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, sql-delete

I'm having difficulty deleting the desired rows from my table in MySQL. I'm using a rather complex subquery to select the rows, but for some reason I'm unable to delete them using a similar syntax.

```
delete * from table1 as t1
where t1.col1 in 
(select y.col1 
 from table2 x 
 join 
    (select col1, col2 
     from table2
     where col2 like "%- 2%") y 
 on x.col2 = replace(y.col2, "- 2", ""));
```

Again, I can select the exact rows I wanted deleted, but when I change the query to delete I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `*` after `DELETE`. You don't usually delete individual columns, you delete entire rows.

Answer (score 3):

yep, you should use

```
delete from table1
```

or if there are more than one table in the query, you need to enter the name of the table you want to delete from.

```
delete table1 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.t1ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `*`. A DELETE is an all or nothing kind of action.

Answer (score 1):

Try DELETE FROM instead of DELETE * FROM which is not valid.